# How to sum line item of subreport added in SSRS tablix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, dynamics-crm-online, subreport, fetchxml

I've sub-report in one of the SSRS Tablix Cell. It works fine when details grouping is enabled of the tablix. Like below.

`Product | Line Item | Adjusted Billings (sub-report column)`

`XYZ     |  $30      | $45`

`XYZ     |  $30      | $40`

As soon as I group the tablix based on Product then the report comes like below:

`Product | Line Item | Adjusted Billings (sub-report column)`

`XYZ     |  $60      | $45`

But my targeted report output would be like this:

`Product | Line Item | Adjusted Billings (sub-report column)`

`XYZ     |  $60      | $85`

In sub-report, I am also using a tablix with one column and header row is set to invisible. Additionally, I've add `Sum()` in sub-report column as well but still not able to get required results.

Can someone please let me know what I am missing to get required results?

Answer (score 0):

When you add a parent group to your tablix (in your case the `XYZ`) then click the option **Add group header** (or footer). An extra row will appear above the detail row. In the detail row you will see all the detailed data (like you first example table). Above this detail row (the header you added) you can write the following expressions:

```
'First Cell
=Sum(Fields!LineItem.Value)


'Second Cell
=Sum(Fields!AdjustedBillings.Value)
```

Now it will be displayed like you want it. You can additionally hide the detail rows, this way you just the the summed data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I need to use subreport for calculation of Adjusted Billings. I am not sure if your suggested solution will resolve my problem

Comment: What do you mean by sub report? Maybe you can post a picture what you want to achive.

Comment: I can post picture right away, but I've tried to draw the picture in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what is happening is Your sub report cannot group based on Product, It takes the First row and displays it. This is a very classic SSRS issue/use case with Developers.

What I would suggest, Add Product as a Column in your sub report as well and then try grouping on Main Report, If this does not work try grouping in your sub report based on Product as well. This shall work.

Comment: This is what I tried a couple of hours back. but still no luck,

Comment: If I may ask what are you passing as a parameter to your sub report?
Is your product a unique one.
How about you use aggregate in your sub report so that result in sub report itself is summed up

Comment: Parameters to subreport are 6. Region, Product, Line Amount, End Date, Sales Type, and Exchange Rate. Now on the base of first four parameters I receive a constant value that is further used in sub-report for multiplication with Line amount and Exchange rate to calculate  adjusted billings.

Comment: OK can you try creating sub report as a separate Report (Test Report) and see if you are able to group based on Product

Comment: I can group it on the base product. But since there is only one product for a constant value, and if I try to run report separately then the report is working fine. I think we need to group the sub-report on other values but not on parameters passed.

Comment: curious,
Were you able to solve the issue and if yes how??

Comment: No, still trying for way around. By default, I am able to get the sub-report values line by line. But when it comes to get sum of all values being calculated from sub-report is not working.

Comment: OK,
So your sub report right now shows value as something like below
Product Nr Amount
1 40
2 50
1 30
3 70
1 80
2 40

and you wish to achieve like

Product Nr Amount
1 150
2 90
3 70

Comment: I think that is what I've mentioned in my question as Targeted Report output.

Comment: Then I fail to understand when you group your main Report and sub report on Product why don't you get exact result.